How to add imagemagick into php8.2 on my Kubuntu 22.04?
Having php8.2 on my Kubuntu 22.04 :
# php -v
PHP 8.2.25 (cli) (built: Oct 30 2024 11:25:56) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.25, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v8.2.25, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v3.3.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2024, by Derick Rethans

uname -a
Linux master-at-home 6.5.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue May  7 09:00:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I need to install imagemagick and I do it with command :
# sudo apt install --assume-yes php-imagick
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
php8.4-cli php8.4-common php8.4-imagick php8.4-opcache php8.4-phpdbg php8.4-readline
Suggested packages:
php-pear
The following NEW packages will be installed:
php-imagick php8.4-cli php8.4-common php8.4-imagick php8.4-opcache php8.4-phpdbg php8.4-readline
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 5 426 kB of archives.
After this operation, 24,2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 php8.4-common amd64 8.4.0~rc3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [802 kB]
Get:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 php8.4-opcache amd64 8.4.0~rc3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [465 kB]
Get:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 php8.4-readline amd64 8.4.0~rc3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [13,6 kB]
Get:4 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 php8.4-cli amd64 8.4.0~rc3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1 993 kB]
Get:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 php8.4-phpdbg amd64 8.4.0~rc3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [2 014 kB]
Get:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 php8.4-imagick amd64 3.7.0-8+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [125 kB]
Get:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 php-imagick all 3.7.0-8+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [13,1 kB]
Fetched 5 426 kB in 5s (1 054 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package php8.4-common.
(Reading database ... 286663 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-php8.4-common_8.4.0~rc3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.4-common (8.4.0~rc3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php8.4-opcache.
Preparing to unpack .../1-php8.4-opcache_8.4.0~rc3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.4-opcache (8.4.0~rc3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php8.4-readline.
Preparing to unpack .../2-php8.4-readline_8.4.0~rc3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.4-readline (8.4.0~rc3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php8.4-cli.
Preparing to unpack .../3-php8.4-cli_8.4.0~rc3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.4-cli (8.4.0~rc3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php8.4-phpdbg.
Preparing to unpack .../4-php8.4-phpdbg_8.4.0~rc3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.4-phpdbg (8.4.0~rc3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php8.4-imagick.
Preparing to unpack .../5-php8.4-imagick_3.7.0-8+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.4-imagick (3.7.0-8+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php-imagick.
Preparing to unpack .../6-php-imagick_3.7.0-8+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking php-imagick (3.7.0-8+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Setting up php8.4-common (8.4.0~rc3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/8.4/mods-available/calendar.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/8.4/mods-available/ctype.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/8.4/mods-available/exif.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/8.4/mods-available/fileinfo.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/8.4/mods-available/ffi.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/8.4/mods-available/ftp.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/8.4/mods-available/gettext.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/8.4/mods-available/iconv.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/8.4/mods-available/pdo.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/8.4/mods-available/phar.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/8.4/mods-available/posix.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/8.4/mods-available/shmop.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/8.4/mods-available/sockets.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/8.4/mods-available/sysvmsg.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/8.4/mods-available/sysvsem.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/8.4/mods-available/sysvshm.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/8.4/mods-available/tokenizer.ini with new version
Setting up php8.4-opcache (8.4.0~rc3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/8.4/mods-available/opcache.ini with new version
Setting up php8.4-readline (8.4.0~rc3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/8.4/mods-available/readline.ini with new version
Setting up php8.4-cli (8.4.0~rc3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/8.4/cli/php.ini with new version
Setting up php8.4-imagick (3.7.0-8+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Setting up php8.4-phpdbg (8.4.0~rc3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/phpdbg8.4 to provide /usr/bin/phpdbg (phpdbg) in auto mode

Creating config file /etc/php/8.4/phpdbg/php.ini with new version
Setting up php-imagick (3.7.0-8+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for php8.4-cli (8.4.0~rc3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Processing triggers for php8.4-phpdbg (8.4.0~rc3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...

What confuse me in output above that is php8.4, but I use php8.2
I restart apache2 with success:
# service apache2 restart

and check
# php --modules | grep imagick

But last line returns empty line so imagemagick was not installed ?
In output of phpinfo there no no any imagemagick mantioned...
What is wrong ?
DETAILED INFORMATION :
I added
extension=imagick.so

line in ; Dynamic Extensions ; block of both /etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini and /etc/php/8.2/apache2/php.ini
and restarting
service apache2 restart

I got error :
root@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts# php --modules | grep imagick
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20220829/imagick.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/imagick.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20220829/imagick.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/imagick.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

What is wrong ?

The sentence makes no sense: "What confuse me in output above that is php8.4, but I use php8.4" - do you mean "I use php8.2"?

Did you edit the php.ini file and enable the module?

Please which settings have I to set in php.ini file under kubuntu 22.04?

I believe you should add a line extension=imagick.so in the Dynamic Extensions section of php.ini.

Please read DETAILED INFORMATION

Yes, I  mean "I use php8.2"
